# Creating JDBC Connection with Oracle 10g using jsp

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc

I am able to connect to Oracle 10g (using ojdbc14.jar driver) with java. But when I use the same code in a servlet or file with .jsp extension, I am getting class not found exception. I am not able to understand why this is happening. Do we have different connection strings for JDBC in java and jsp? This is what I use to connect to oracle iwith both, java and jsp:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
//Xe being the database name
String usr = "username";
String pwd = "pwd";
```

Works fine with java but gives error with jsp.

Comment: You forgot to tell about the error. There are zillion kinds of errors, each telling on its own way about the cause of the problem. Not telling anything about the error will make the cause underterminable and the problem hard to solve.

Comment: When I use oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, it gives me class not found exception.

Comment: I know the post is pretty old but still thought of to write the error that I can see in your code. You can use oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver instead and try.

Comment: @somnathchakrabarti: That wasn't the issue. The issue was that the server was not able to find the jar. And after following instructions from wds, things started working fine.

Comment: ok I see. I encountered some similar problem yesterday. Despite adding the classes.jar and ojdbc14.jar under system classpath, I have to also manually add them under the WEB_INF/lib folder of my application. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no real difference between the two. Is the driver jar in your WEB-INF/lib/ subdirectory? A class not found exception typically means your jar wasn't found on the classpath.

Comment: The drivers jar is included in the class path. If I am creating a java file in same project, it works fine. Problem is with jsp only.

Comment: Which server are you using? And what path within the server folder have you placed the ojdbc14.jar ?

Comment: @Logan - that's not what he asked you.  Is the JAR in WEB-INF/lib?  If you're using a system CLASSPATH, you need to know that your app server ignores it.

Comment: @Logan: are you running the application server by launching from your IDE somehow? Perhaps it is a configuration problem.

Comment: I have imported the jar in project and am not using system classpath.

Comment: @wds: yes the jar is in the Web-Inf/lib/folder

Comment: @Logan: just to make sure, that's WEB-INF upper case. It sometimes matters. Run `jar tf` on the war you made and check whether it really does include everything correctly.

Comment: hi, Thanks. That's what I was searching. But What I am missing is the .jar file.
Can you please send me the .jar file requires for this? or link form where I can download that?

Comment: @Arslan the first hit for oracle jdbc drivers: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Answer (score 4):

i found the solution to this...

it's very easy... i would be specific to oracle database and apache tomcat server.

download ojdbc6.jar from oracle or any source

place it in your tomcat/lib/ (no matter if you use xampp or any amp bundle, it is there)
RESTART YOUR SERVER its a must, otherwise you would be wondering only lolz.

try this code it works..!!

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple JSP to Oracle connection Example</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<%
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");
        out.println("connected....!!");

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "");
    }


%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a CLASSPATH environment variable, your app server ignores it.  That's probably why it "works" with Java but not with JSPs.

I'd advise you to not rely on CLASSPATH that way.  Learn how to set it properly for every situation.

I'd also advise against putting scriptlet code in JSPs.  This will grow to be a maintenance nightmare in a short time.

If you must put database calls in a JSP, learn how to use JSTL and its `<sql>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="oracle.jdbc.driver.*" %>
<%@page import="oracle.sql.*;" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="but1.jsp">
<label>
    Sr No:<input type="text" name="txt" /></br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="txt1" />
</label>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="but1" id="but1" value="Submit">


  </input>   
    <% String s=request.getParameter("txt");
    System.out.print(s);

    String s1=request.getParameter("txt1");


Connection con;

Statement st;

ResultSet rs;

try{
       System.out.println("hi");
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
       System.out.println("1"); 
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","oracle-uname","oracle-password");
       System.out.println("2");
   st=con.createStatement();
       System.out.println("3");
   String query="insert into table1(srno, name) values ("+s+",'"+s1+"')";
       System.out.println("4");
       int rRs=st.executeUpdate(query);
       System.out.println("5");
       String q="Select * from table1 where srno="+s+"";
       System.out.println("cats");
   rs=st.executeQuery(q);
       System.out.println("catty");
       while(rs.next())
       {
            System.out.println("6");
    out.println("number is: "+rs.getString(1));%>
            </br>
            <%out.print("name is: "+rs.getString(2));           
       } 
    }

catch(Exception ee)

{
    System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"=path

to set path.. 
services > databases > drivers > oracle thin > connect using > add jar ojdbc6.jar > next > jdbc url (at the bottom) > set uname to system, and password to oracle password > test connection

the jdbc url forms the path ie "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"

all the best

Comment: so, what is the point in your answer? I don't get what you mean specifically